# Button beside Tabs in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create a button beside tabs in android in such a way that it should not overlap with the tabs.It is like calendar application in android which has "List" tab(for planning),"Day" tab (for each day plan) and "Month" tab(for displaying calendar).I want to add another button(Today) beside the tabs so that if I click "Today" it should display the current date incase I navigate to some other date from the tab.I tried by

```
Button button = new Button(this);
button.setText("Today");
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);    
tabHost.addView(button,params);
```

But in this case the button is overlapping the tabs which I don't want.

Any help????

Thanks in advance

Comment: you put tick then remove? why?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put the `TabWidget` object which is called *tabs* in a LinearLayout with `android:orientation="horizontal"`

Now add the button to the LinearLayout instead of the tabHost.

Comment: This works but the last tab is not functioning,that is it is not starting the activity that it should  when clicked